# representing a tree as a list in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm learning python and I'm curious about how people choose to store (binary) trees in python.

Is there something wrong in storing the nodes of the tree as a list in python? something like:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

where the 0'th position is 0 by default, 1 is the root, and for each position (i), the 2i and 2i+1 positions are the children. When no child is present, we just have a 'None' in that position.

I've read a couple of books/notes where they represent a tree using a list of lists, or something more complicated than just a simple list like this, and I was wondering if there's something inherently wrong in how i'm looking at it?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such a tree? My first attempt would be using lists of lists (like you would like to do) or dicts.

Comment: Imagine a tree where the left child of the root has no children, and the right child 10,000 children.

Comment: Seems like a sparsely populated tree would have a whole lot of `None` objects for no reason. Why do it this way?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do this, but I'm not entirely clear why you would want to...I feel like it's needlessly complex out of some desire to make it flat.

Comment: This is how you'd usually represent a non-sparse binary tree in C. It's efficient and fast. But why not introduce a layer of abstraction when you're using a nicer language like Python? It doesn't hurt, especially if you need to modify the tree structure in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly COULD do this. I'd define it as a class deriving from list with a `get_children` method. However this is fairly ugly since either A) you'd have to preprocess the whole list in O(n) time to pair up indices with values or B) you'd have to call `list.index` in O(n log n) time to traverse the tree.

```
class WeirdBinaryTreeA(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_children(value):
        """Calls list.index on value to derive the children"""
        idx = self.index(value)  # O(n) once, O(n log n) to traverse
        return self[idx * 2], self[idx * 2 + 1]


class WeirdBinaryTreeB(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__mapping = self.processtree()

    def processtree(self):
        for idx, val in enumerate(self):
            self.__mapping[val] = idx

    def get_children(value):
        """Queries the mapping on value to derive the children"""
        idx = self.__mapping[value]  # O(1) once, O(n) to traverse
        return self[idx * 2], self[idx * 2 + 1]
```

However the bigger question is *why* would you do this? What makes it better than a list of lists or a dict of dicts? What happens when you have:

```
    A
   / \
      B
     / \
        C
       / \
          D
         / \
            E
           / \
              F
```

And your list looks like:

```
[0, 'A', None, 'B', None, None, None, 'C', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'D', ...]
```

Instead of:

```
{"A": {"B": {"C": {"D": {"E": {"F": None}}}}}}
```

Comment: I understand. thanks. There's a certain convenience with the flat list structure though, especially when doing a breadth first type traversal.

Comment: Certainly! And for sure a densely-packed tree would be cheaper to store in such a flat list, but for an unknown general case, it's easier to abstract.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with storing a binary tree as a list the way you're doing - it's the same idea as storing it as a flat array in a language like C or Java. Accessing the parent of a given node is very fast, and finding the children is also pretty efficient.

I suppose a lot of examples and tutorials will prefer to use a representation that's 'really tree shaped' (list of lists or objects) - it might be a bit more intuitive to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen representations like this (your flat list/array) used in C code, and representations like this could be acceptable in Python too, but it depends on the nature of the data you're handling. In C code, a balanced tree in this list representation can be very fast to access (much quicker than navigating a series of pointers), though the performance benefit in Python may be less noticeable due to all the other overhead.

For reasonably balanced dense trees, this flat list approach is reasonable. However, as Adam Smith commented, this type of flat list tree would become extremely wasteful for unbalanced sparse trees. Suppose you have one branch with single children going down a hundred levels, and the rest of the tree had nothing. You would need 2^100 + 2^99 + 2^98 + ... + 2^1 + 1 spots in the flat list tree. For such a case, you would use up a huge amount of memory for something that could be represented much more efficiently with nested lists.

So in essence, the choice between flat list trees vs. nested list trees is similar to the choice between flat array trees and pointer based trees in a C like language.

Comment: this makes sense. I was thiking mostly about balanced trees when I typed the question, and unbalanced trees will definitely screw it up in terms of storage